# Laravel Socialite get more information about the user - user_location

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-socialite

I want other fields from the users facebook when they login like ***user_location***

Now I came to know that I need to submit an app for review in order to get approved for fetching the users location. Also Facebook has already approved it.

Now I'm trying to fetch using the following code:

```
$this->socialite->driver($provider)->scopes(['user_location', 'user_hometown'])->redirect()
```

but when I dump this:

```
$this->socialite->driver($provider)->user();
```

It doesn't provide me user_location in the array of user data. But facebook asked for the permission for it when I tried to logged in for the first time.

This is the data which I'm getting:

```
User {#330 ▼
  +token: "xxxxxxxxxx"
  +refreshToken: null
  +expiresIn: "xxxxx"
  +id: "xxxxxx"
  +nickname: null
  +name: "xxxxxx"
  +email: "xxxxxx@xx.com"
  +avatar: "xxxxxx"
  +user: array:5 [▶]
  +"avatar_original": "xxxxxxxx"
}
```

So May I know, what I'm doing wrong, and how can I get the user location.

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use fields() method in your redirect method to set additional fields and use them later in you application.

```
public function redirectToFacebook()
{
    return $this->socialite->driver($provider)->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender','location'
    ])->scopes([
        'user_location'
    ])->redirect();
}
```

Then later access them with:

```
public function handleFacebookCallback()
{
    $providerUser = $this->socialite->driver($provider)->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday','location'
    ])->user();

    dd($providerUser);
}
```

Note that fields() will overwrite the defaults, so in the example above you won't get "verified" and "link" properties for user.